# Почему не работает JavaScript таблица в Asp.Net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Код у меня следующего вида:

ASP

```
     <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Фамилия</th>
                                        <th>Имя</th>
                                        <th>Email</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                  </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><%#Eval("Name")%></td>
                                        <td><%#Eval("Family")%></td>
                                        <td><%#Eval("Email")%></td>
                                    </tr>

                                </tbody>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                            </table>
                           </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
```

На стороне сервера:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetMailList jsonstring = new GetMailList();

                JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonstring.GetJson());

                var family = from account in json["accounts"] select account["fname"].Value<string>();
                var name = from account in json["accounts"] select account["iname"].Value<string>();
                var email = from account in json["accounts"] select account["login"].Value<string>();
                // Соединяем три коллекции
                var combineColl = from account in json["accounts"]
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      family = account["fname"].Value<string>(),
                                      name = account["iname"].Value<string>(),
                                      email = account["login"].Value<string>()
                                  };

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Family", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));

                int i = 1;
                foreach (var one in combineColl)
                {
                    DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();


                    dtrow["Family"] = one.family;
                    dtrow["Name"] = one.name;
                    dtrow["Email"] = one.email;

                    dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);
                    i++;
                }
                Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Все прекрасно загружается, но не работают элементы JavaSrcript, сортировка поиск и тд. Убираю репитор и заношу данные вручную все начинает нормально работать.Скажите, где я не прав?
Отображается, будто в таблицу попал один элемент. На самом деле в таблице их 100.

Comment: А вы чем сортируете на javascript? проблема скорее всего в селекторе...

Comment: http://datatables.net/ использую эту библиотеку.  Она воспринимает, будто в таблицу попал один элемент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ! дело было в `<tbody></tbody>`. Удалил их и все заработало.